# CakePHP: Data sanitization while updating

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a problem with sanitization. In AppController I'm using Sanitization utility but It doesn't work. When I want to call my update It fails because of **'** slash in my input text. I'm using CakePHP 2.3.6.

```
function beforeFilter(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');
        $this->request->data = Sanitize::clean($this->data, array('remove_html'=>true,'encode'=>false,'unicode'=>false,'backslash'=>true, 'escape'=>false));
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
$this->ClientProfile->updateAll(
    array('ClientProfile.location'=>"'".$this->User->data['ClientProfile']['location']."'"),
    array('ClientProfile.user_id'=>$userdata['id'])
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Very confused with your code. Why do you use `$this->User->data[etc]` when you sanitized the `$this->request->data` array (where do you even get a `$this->User->data`?) ? 2) There's no need to put `App::uses` inside the beforefilter, declare it on top, the utilities are lazyloaded.

Comment: I highly recommend not to apply any sanitation on save. The rule is: "leave input alone, escape output". So just escape your output using `h()` as documented (also see the new note @ http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#Sanitize::html ) and you will be fine.

Comment: Please check my answer. If it's useful, set the answer as accepted or vote it up. Otherwise just write what's missing in the answer or what are the problems you're dealing with now and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Sanitize::escape() instead of Sanitize::clean(). As it's written in [the documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Sanitize.html#_escape),

> Sanitize::escape()
>
> Makes a string SQL-safe.

You may also move data sanitization directly to updateAll() method call. By doing this you will know that updateAll() method will get sanitized data, no matter what happened with this data in other parts of your script.